# Use of the word "topology" in physics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, mathematical-physics

I don't know so much about topological order or topological phase transition or topological state of matter or other similar expressions from physics and mathematical-physics, but I can't see a direct link to topology in a strict mathematical sense.

So, in which sense is the word topology used in these fields? 
How much *"real"* topology is involved?

Comment: My definition of topology is "the study of open sets."  This is a very very broad definition.  I don't know much about the topics you mentioned, but TQFT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory) seems to be related to them (in TQFT, one studies topological invariants).  There's a lot of topology there :)

Comment: Yes, in TQFT there is a lot of topology, I know some instrument used in TQFT and there is really a lot of topology, but I don't know specifically in these cases if and how is used "topology"

Comment: Topology in physics is mainly used to set up continuous maps into discrete sets which then become locally constant. This property of being locally constant is extremely relevant for experiments.